# Running Pipenv shell in new gnome terminal tab

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, pipenv

I am attempting to run a script that opens several gnome terminal tabs and then run commands in a Pipenv environment. In order to make sure that I run the commands after `~/.bashrc`, I followed the answer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/198015/open-gnome-terminal-programmatically-and-execute-commands-after-bashrc-was-execu) question. This seems to work without a problem. However, the issue comes when I run this command to start a Django server in a virtual environment:

```bsh
BASH_POST_RC='pipenv shell && ./manage.py runserver' gnome-terminal --tab --title="My tab"
```

The command results in the following:

> Loading .env environment variables... Launching subshell in virtual
>   environment...  .
>   /home/daniel/.local/share/virtualenvs/my-env/bin/activate Shell for
>   UNKNOWN_VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT already activated. No action taken to
>   avoid nested environments.

It would seem somehow that it thinks it is already in the virtual environment, which is not the case. And I'm not in the virtual environment when I run the command in the first place. Furthermore, no other commands seem to run after `pipenv shell`. It just does nothing.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that Pipenv has a [`run`](https://docs.pipenv.org/en/latest/#other-commands) command to run python scrips directly in your virtual environment. So all I did was use:

```
BASH_POST_RC='pipenv run python manage.py runserver' gnome-terminal --tab --title="Django server"
```